# How to optimize wifi usb for gaming in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, games, steam

I currently have a custom built desktop running Ubuntu 16.04 with an Nvidia GTX 550 and a TP-Link TL-WN822N.

The WiFi runs great for web browsing, downloading and music/video streaming. The only issue I ever have is when I run steam and play games like Team Fortress 2.

Every couple of minutes I experience a drop in internet connection, I'll be in the game and I can see my signal strength in the TF2 game go from full green to a sudden yellow signal strength and the game will stutter a bit before regaining its full speed.

I have tried following the optimizations provided by [Speed Up Slow WiFi Connection](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/). In my current setup I have done every solution the blog suggested, but I'm still coming up with a stutter/lag every couple of minutes in the game. My video settings is relatively minimal, so I do not believe my graphics card has anything to do with the stutter/lag.

My router is the stock Xfinity router. I have not made any modifications to it, but am not sure if any setting adjustment are required by that.

If anyone can suggest what WiFi settings needs to be changed to allow for the game to stop stuttering, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that can cause what you describe. You didn't help your situation with the "Speed up slow wifi connection" blog. But never mind that for now.

I have two quick recommendations out of the blue for you.

1. in terminal, type `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`. Replace `wlan0` with the correct name for your wireless adapter. This will turn off power management for your adapter, and allow it to run full speed all the time.
2. make sure that your connection is using `WPA2-AES`. This will assure the fastest connection.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks, I tried both what you've recommended, and it still does the stutter every few minutes during gameplay. I tested out playing through the local Xfinity wifi instead of my router, and am now finding it is my wifi usb TP-Link TL-WN822N that may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why my WiFi kept lagging every few minutes when I play games online. After searching the internet a little more, I came across [this](https://steamcommunity.com/groups/homestream/discussions/0/540735426854884989/) forum on steam.

The solution to eliminate the lagging is to remove the default network manager on Ubuntu and install WICD. Following [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD) guide will help removing the network manager and using WICD as the new network manager.

I'm finally able to play shooter games without missing a split second.